# Angular Reactive Form child component is not showing value after using form.patchvalue

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, angular8

I have component that uses reactive form that has a child component that has a select element. The problem is after I the component loads my select element does not have a value. I'm expecting the select element to show the value from @input of the parent component..

```
<parent-component>
   <form [formGroup]="myForm">
      <child-component>
          (optionIsSelected)="doSomething()"
          [data]="data"
          [optionsList]="options"
      </child-component>
   </form>
</parent-component>
```

And in my child component

```
<select formControlName="mySelect" (change)="handleChange()>
   <option selected="true">{{text}}</option>
        <option *ngFor="let option of options; trackBy: trackByFn"[value]="option.value">
            {{ option.data}}
        </option>
</select>
```

child TS:

```
@data
form: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
        mySelect: [null]
    });
set value(value: any) {
        this._value = value;
        this.form.patchValue({ mySelect: this.value });
}

ngOnChanges(changes) { // this is where I patch the value from @Input of parent
   if (changes['data']) {
       const myData = JSON.stringify(changes['data].currentValue);
       this.form.patchValue({ mySelect: myData });
   }
}
```

My select element only shows empty after this.. My parent component is a sidebar so everytime I open it, it should load the select element value from my parent component via @Input..